# How to convert recursive function to generator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, generator

I have the following recursive function to generate a list of valid configurations for a (named) list of positions, where each position can be used only once:

```
def generate_configurations(configurations, named_positions, current):
    if len(current) == len(named_positions):
        configurations.append(current)
        return configurations

    name, positions = named_positions[len(current)]
    for x in positions:
        if x not in current:
            generate_configurations(configurations, named_positions, current + (x,))

    return configurations
```

Here is an example of how I call it:

```
named_positions = [('a', [0,1,2]),
                   ('b', [1,3]),
                   ('c', [1,2])]

for comb in generate_configurations([], named_positions, ()):
    print comb
```

Which gives the following output:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 1)
```

Also, it is possible there are *no* valid combinations, e.g. for `named_positions = [('a', [3]), ('b', [3])]`.

Now depending on the input `named_positions`, the `configurations` list can quickly become huge, resulting in a `MemoryError`. I believe this function could be re-written as a generator, so I tried the following:

```
def generate_configurations(named_positions, current):
    if len(current) == len(named_positions):
        yield current

    name, positions = named_positions[len(current)]
    for x in positions:
        if x not in current:
            generate_configurations(named_positions, current + (x,))

named_positions = [('a', [0,1,2]),
                   ('b', [1,3]),
                   ('c', [1,2])]

for comb in generate_configurations(named_positions, ()):
    print comb
```

but this doesn't generate any results at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `yield` up the recursive call stack or the inner `yield`s never happen and get discarded. Since this is tagged Python 2.7, the recursive calls would be handled by changing:

```
if x not in current:
    # Creates the generator, but doesn't run it out to get and yield values
    generate_configurations(named_positions, current + (x,))
```

to:

```
if x not in current:
    # Actually runs the generator and yields values up the call stack
    for y in generate_configurations(named_positions, current + (x,)):
        yield y
```

In Python 3.3 and higher, you can delegate directly with:

```
if x not in current:
    yield from generate_configurations(named_positions, current + (x,)):
```

Comment: Thanks, that works now - I also had to add a `return` statement just after `yield current` to avoid it recursing further than it should.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using generators, you need to make sure that your sub-generator recursive calls pass back up to the calling method.

```
def recur_generator(n):
    yield my_thing
    yield my_other_thing
    if n > 0:
        yield from recur_generator(n-1)
```

Notice here that the `yield from` is what passes the yield calls back up to the parent call.

You should change the recursive call line to

```
yield from generate_configurations(named_positions, current + (x,))
```

Otherwise, your generator is fine.

EDIT: Didn't notice that this was python2. You can use

```
for x in recur_generator(n-1):
    yield x
```

instead of `yield from`.